# InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list

Tags: infopath, field-definition

The error I'm getting when I click Customize Form on a list.

**InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list**
Missing equals sign between attribute and attribute value.

The list content type and instance is deployed using a feature. It works well when the list field types are Text, Number, Choice, Number and Lookup. But when I add a User field InfoPath just complain with that error.

I tried to add as many attribute as I can and here's the CAML for the field.

```
<Field ID="{DBA48417-D25E-4DE3-985E-8584335B97A5}" Name="Account Manager" DisplayName="Account Manager" StaticName="AccountManager"
                  Type="User" List="UserInfo" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ShowField="ImnName" UserSelectionMode="0" UserSelectionScope="0"
                  Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" ColName="int1" RowOrdinal="0"
                  SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"  Group="Test.Group" Version="1" 
                  ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" 
>
</Field>
```

It shows up in the Site Columns and as a field inside my content type. Why does the Customize Form doesn't work?

If I try to deploy the feature without the User type. Then add the User type using the UI  (create site column then add it to the content type) the Customize Form just works.

Comment: Is this a field that you did a custom definition for or created via the GUI?

Comment: When added the User type is added through custom definition it doesn't work. If the "Person or Group" field is added through the GUI it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had made some changes on the list schema.xml file. So instead of just adding a ContentTypeRef like:

```
<ContentTypes>
   <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0100687A03E793634417B79B406E7B6E71E1" /> 
</ContentTypes>
```

I have to include the whole content type definition like:

```
<ContentTypes>
    <ContentType ID="0x0100e55b14c3163b40ea92ec91e72fdf1041" Name="Content Type Name" Description="Content Type Description" >
       <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{DBA48417-D25E-4DE3-985E-8584335B97A5}" Name="AccountExecutive" />
          ...
          <FieldRef ID="{34CF685A-E9B7-4E55-A884-21995BD42049}" Name="QuoteNumbers" />
       </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
<ContentTypes>
```