# A name contained an invalid character and InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list

Tags: forms-services

I have few custom site columns and a content type created out of it. I am using the same Content Type in my List. Everything is done through declarative XML in Visual Studio.

I tried to add as many attribute as I can and here's the CAML for the field.
It shows up in the Site Columns and as a field inside my content type. Why does the Customize Form not work?

I referred a thread and but I don't know how he found out that SharePoint list Missing equals sign between attribute and attribute value.

[InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35230/infopath-cannot-generate-a-form-template-for-the-sharepoint-list)

If I try to deploy the feature without the User type. Then add the User type using the UI (create site column then add it to the content type) the Customize Form just works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="CTS SP Governance - CTS SP Governance - CTS Approval Call Request" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/GTICTSSharePointGovernance-CTSApprovalCallRequest" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <MetaData>
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentType ID="0x0100e79bc1ee2b0e4c1f8b0db5e7ed8ab480" Name="CTS SP Governance - CTS Approval Request" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" Description="Used for CTS Approval Request" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{0BE8D667-E69B-414F-AC45-CF6D024BAD77}" Name="ApprovalCallDate" DisplayName="Approval Call Date" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{579946B2-24DF-42CF-90D4-7E207EB12049}" Name="Item" DisplayName="Item" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{E7201738-0835-41DB-AEE0-5DEE9AA65411}" Name="TitleNameBCXXX" DisplayName="Title (#, Name: i.e. BC XXXX)" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{C6D5DB8F-9C46-4396-A7AB-916FB712F728}" Name="Presenter" DisplayName="Presenter" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{274963E0-08DF-454C-82A9-9A14C0FD573B}" Name="TotalSpend" DisplayName="Total Spend" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{A4D88668-70A0-4655-A1CE-04E7CFE731C3}" Name="2015PLexFTE" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L exFTE" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{504F4F9E-2FD2-4BC7-9BDA-9A3247FBF210}" Name="2015PLBud" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L Bud" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{27F4217E-6E4D-4020-A5A7-D2A62DC3741A}" Name="Approvers" DisplayName="Approvers" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{47F068BA-DC6F-4A01-AACA-6C7B6FE737F5}" Name="FollowUps" DisplayName="Follow Ups" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{DEC0743A-A877-4A9C-A7C3-2A178EF5FADE}" Name="RequestStatus" DisplayName="Request Status" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{63A8E419-68C0-432E-AD03-2C8DF98D51EE}" Name="DateofGeorgeapprovalcall" DisplayName="Date of George's approval call" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{9BAFA6D7-F3CA-4FD4-977A-4ED4611BDD6B}" Name="Dec15HC" DisplayName="Dec15 HC" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{3D94D1B3-37C5-4936-B8DF-65867C6BF5E6}" Name="IncrHC" DisplayName="Incr HC" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{31CF38B5-5E37-4232-988B-ECF6785D5ACF}" Name="Order" DisplayName="Order" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{F8FC9261-14E6-4146-B790-A65E1F38531B}" Name="Description" DisplayName="Description" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{BE102053-C931-43D8-A01B-2066B3FBAD87}" Name="TPOLink" DisplayName="TPO Link" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{07EAF874-71F9-4ABD-B809-4D10AE45850F}" Name="Requestor" DisplayName="Requestor" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{1F900BF0-FCF8-42AC-9BB6-098E6C11847A}" Name="ApprovalDueDate" DisplayName="Approval Due Date" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{A23AA12B-0EDC-4372-BB18-DAABB5E89ED7}" Name="Deadline" DisplayName="Deadline" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{1A8C6040-21B4-4CEE-A3B1-FC6E1C1F5618}" Name="RequestorSID" DisplayName="Requestor SID" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{E664D4A3-CC6F-4985-878B-3FB6FED845BF}" Name="LevelDSID" DisplayName="LevelD SID" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{7C0B8121-611D-4365-BE9A-5B446E255FF8}" Name="LevelCSID" DisplayName="LevelC SID" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{0BA0FD95-5E82-4303-9C58-938242861480}" Name="LevelBSID" DisplayName="LevelB SID" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" Required="TRUE" />
      <RemoveFieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title"></RemoveFieldRef>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</ContentTypes>
<Fields>
  <Field ID="{0be8d667-e69b-414f-ac45-cf6d024bad77}" Type="DateTime" Format="DateOnly" DisplayName="Approval Call Date" StaticName="AppovalCallDate" Name="ApprovalCallDate" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{579946b2-24df-42cf-90d4-7e207eb12049}" Type="Choice" DisplayName="Item"  StaticName="Item" Name="RItem" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Business Case</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Epurchase</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Headcount</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>B2P</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>WRM</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Risk CSA</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>TPO</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Other</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
<Default>Business Case</Default>
</Field>
  <Field ID="{e7201738-0835-41db-aee0-5dee9aa65411}" Type="Text" DisplayName="Title (#, Name: i.e. BC XXXX)" StaticName="TitleNameBCXXX" Name="RTitleNameBCXXX" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{c6d5db8f-9c46-4396-a7ab-916fb712f728}" Type="User" DisplayName="Presenter" StaticName="Presenter" Name="RPresenter" List="UserInfo" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Mult="TRUE" ShowField="Name" Presence="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"  Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{274963e0-08df-454c-82a9-9a14c0fd573b}" Type="Currency" LCID="3081" DisplayName="Total Spend" StaticName="TotalSpend" Name="TotalSpend" Decimals="0" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{a4d88668-70a0-4655-a1ce-04e7cfe731c3}" Type="Currency" LCID="3081" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L exFTE" Decimals="0" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="2015PLexFTE" Name="2015PLexFTE">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{504f4f9e-2fd2-4bc7-9bda-9a3247fbf210}" Type="Currency" LCID="3081" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L Bud" Decimals="0" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="2015PLBud" Name="2015PLBud">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{27f4217e-6e4d-4020-a5a7-d2a62dc3741a}" Type="User" List="UserInfo" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Mult="TRUE" ShowField="Name" Presence="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" DisplayName="Approvers" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Approvers" Name="Approvers">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{47f068ba-dc6f-4a01-aaca-6c7b6fe737f5}" Type="Note" DisplayName="Follow Ups" Description="Approval Call Request Follow Ups" Required="FALSE" NumLines="10" RichText="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="FollowUps" Name="FollowUps" AllowHyperlink="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="FALSE" AppendOnly="FALSE">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{dec0743a-a877-4a9c-a7c3-2a178ef5fade}" Type="Text" DisplayName="Request Status" Required="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="RequestStatus" Name="RequestStatus">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{63a8e419-68c0-432e-ad03-2c8df98d51ee}" Type="DateTime" Format="DateOnly" DisplayName="Date of George's approval call" Required="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="DateofGeorgeapprovalcall" Name="DateofGeorgeapprovalcall">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{9bafa6d7-f3ca-4fd4-977a-4ed4611bdd6b}" Type="Number" Decimals="0" Commas="FALSE" DisplayName="Dec15 HC" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Dec15HC" Name="Dec15HC">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{3d94d1b3-37c5-4936-b8df-65867c6bf5e6}" Type="Number" Decimals="0" Commas="FALSE" DisplayName="Incr HC" Required="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="IncrHC" Name="IncrHC">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{31cf38b5-5e37-4232-988b-ecf6785d5acf}" Type="Number" Decimals="0" Commas="FALSE" DisplayName="Order" Required="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Order" Name="ROrder">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{f8fc9261-14e6-4146-b790-a65e1f38531b}" Type="Note" DisplayName="Description" Description="Approval Call Request Description" Required="FALSE" NumLines="6" RichText="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Description" Name="RDescription" AllowHyperlink="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="FALSE" AppendOnly="FALSE">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{be102053-c931-43d8-a01b-2066b3fbad87}" Type="Note" DisplayName="TPO Link" Description="TPO Link" Required="FALSE" NumLines="3" RichText="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="TPOLink" Name="TPOLink" AllowHyperlink="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="FALSE" AppendOnly="FALSE">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{07eaf874-71f9-4abd-b809-4d10ae45850f}" Type="User" List="UserInfo" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Mult="TRUE" ShowField="Name" Presence="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" DisplayName="Requestor" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Requestor" Name="Requestor">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{a23aa12b-0edc-4372-bb18-daabb5e89ed7}" Type="Number" Decimals="0" Commas="FALSE" DisplayName="Deadline" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance" StaticName="Deadline" Name="Deadline">
<Default>3</Default>
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{1f900bf0-fcf8-42ac-9bb6-098e6c11847a}" Type="Calculated" ResultType="DateTime" Format="DateTime" DisplayName="Approval Due Date" StaticName="ApprovalDueDate" Name="ApprovalDueDate" Description="Due Date for Approval Request" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
<Formula>=IF(WEEKDAY([Created]+[Deadline])=1,[Created]+[Deadline]+2,IF(WEEKDAY([Created]+[Deadline])=7,[Created]+[Deadline]+2,[Created]+[Deadline]))</Formula>
 </Field>
  <Field ID="{1a8c6040-21b4-4cee-a3b1-fc6e1c1f5618}" Type="Text" DisplayName="Requestor SID" StaticName="RequestorSID" Name="RequestorSID" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{e664d4a3-cc6f-4985-878b-3fb6fed845bf}" Type="Text" DisplayName="LevelD SID" StaticName="LevelDSID" Name="LevelDSID" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{7c0b8121-611d-4365-be9a-5b446e255ff8}" Type="Text" DisplayName="LevelC SID" StaticName="LevelCSID" Name="LevelCSID" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{0ba0fd95-5e82-4303-9c58-938242861480}" Type="Text" DisplayName="LevelB SID" StaticName="LevelBSID" Name="LevelBSID" Required="TRUE" Group="CTS SharePoint Governance">
  </Field>
</Fields>
<Views>
  <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu">
      </FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
        </FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments">
      </FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
      </FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID">
        </FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
</MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right away and similar to your def I've had columns beginning with a number like

```
<FieldRef ID="{A4D88668-70A0-4655-A1CE-04E7CFE731C3}" Name="2015PLexFTE" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L exFTE" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{504F4F9E-2FD2-4BC7-9BDA-9A3247FBF210}" Name="2015PLBud" DisplayName="2015 P&amp;L Bud" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
```

I removed these fields or renamed it and finally InfoPath could generate a template.